# Symfony2 Session as Entity / Clearing old sessions without remember me

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine-orm, doctrine

how i can use the $sessData, which is a blob?

**Example entity**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sessions")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Session
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_id", type="string", length=128)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $sessId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_data", type="blob", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $sessData;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_time", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $sessTime;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_lifetime", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $sessLifetime;
}
```

Example command.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Session;

/**
 * Class ClearSessionsCommand
 * @package Acme\UserBundle\Command
 */
class ClearSessionsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('acme:clear:sessions')
            ->setDescription('Deletes old sessions from database')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        /** @var \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine */
        $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
        $repository = $doctrine->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Session');
        $sessions = $repository->findAll();

        foreach($sessions as $session)
        {
            /** @var Session $session */
            var_dump($session->getSessData());
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the output.

```
class Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Session#460 (4) {
    private $sessId =>       string(26) "5v0as58i11vgikih7rb0b7fg41"
    private $sessData =>     resource(419) of type (stream)
    private $sessTime =>     int(1421508757)
    private $sessLifetime => int(1440)
}
```

I'll hope you can help me.

I also tried to use "array", "simple_array" and "json_array".
But if i view the value in plain text i have a format like this.

```
_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:18:"_csrf/authenticate";s:43:"esEvNzkJgkPN3JcgVWO71ArAHnoMxK_ChC1qdXT4bM4";s:14:"_security_main";s:691:"C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":603:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:4:"main";i:2;s:563:"a:4:{i:0;C:26:"Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User":227:{a:9:{i:0;s:88:"4T+akBl30pcGyIDl3MB64TT/o4izQZ/CA/JDHurok50o33g3L0bEgDYMj+itI5G6JWQmzH7gHTrDmLeE7I9yeQ==";i:1;s:31:"cljvnnze8jwo8ck4og8gcg08c4o0ww4";i:2;s:8:"max";i:3;s:8:"Max";i:4;b:0;i:5;b:0;i:6;b:0;i:7;b:1;i:8;i:1;}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:2:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"
```

And i dont know whats this could be for a format.

If i remove `_sf2_attributes|` it might be serialized.

I would delete all sessions where older than one day and not logged in with remembered option.

Thanks in Advance!